# Recieved import error while importing joblib from sklearn.externals

Tags: python, scikit-learn, joblib

Exectued the followwing code

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, make_response
from flask_restplus import Api, Resource, fields
from sklearn.externals import joblib
import numpy as np
import sys

flask_app = Flask(__name__)
app = Api(app = flask_app, 
          version = "1.0", 
          title = "ML React App", 
          description = "Predict results using a trained model")

name_space = app.namespace('prediction', description='Prediction APIs')

model = app.model('Prediction params', 
                  {'Recency': fields.Float(required = True, 
                                               description="Recency Value", 
                                               help="Recency Value cannot be blank"),
                  'Frequency': fields.Float(required = True, 
                                               description="Frequency Value", 
                                               help="Frequency Value cannot be blank"),
                  'Monetary': fields.Float(required = True, 
                                            description="Monetary Value", 
                                            help="Monetary Value cannot be blank"),
                  })

classifier = joblib.load('classifier.joblib')

@name_space.route("/")
class MainClass(Resource):

    def options(self):
        response = make_response()
        response.headers.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', "*")
        response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', "*")
        return response

    @app.expect(model)      
    def post(self):
        try: 
            formData = request.json
            data = [val for val in formData.values()]
            prediction = classifier.predict(np.array(data).reshape(1, -1))
            types = { 0: "Loyal", 1: "NotLoyal"}
            response = jsonify({
                "statusCode": 200,
                "status": "Prediction made",
                "result": "The type of Loyalty is: " + types[prediction[0]]
                })
            response.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
            return response
        except Exception as error:
            return jsonify({
                "statusCode": 500,
                "status": "Could not make prediction",
                "error": str(error)
            })
```

Recieved the following error.

Error: While importing "app", an ImportError was raised:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    **import**(module_name)
  File "D:\dilipan\clg\proj\ML-React-App-Template-master\service\app.py", line 3, in 
    from sklearn.externals import joblib
ImportError: cannot import name 'joblib' from 'sklearn.externals' (d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals__init__.py)

I executed the same in a different pc 2 months ago and it was working fine.

Could not import joblib from sklearn.externals

Any would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Edit :**

I tried using :
`import joblib`
instead of 
`from sklearn.externals import joblib` 
it gave me the following errors

```
File "c:\users\dilipan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "c:\users\dilipan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\dilipan\clg\proj\ML-React-App-Template-master\service\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 967, in main
    cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:], prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 73, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 848, in run_command
    app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 305, in __init__
    self._load_unlocked()
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 330, in _load_unlocked
    self._app = rv = self.loader()
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 392, in load_app
    app = locate_app(self, import_name, None, raise_if_not_found=False)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 240, in locate_app
    __import__(module_name)
  File "D:\dilipan\clg\proj\ML-React-App-Template-master\service\app.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 585, in load
    obj = _unpickle(fobj, filename, mmap_mode)
  File "d:\dilipan\clg\proj\ml-react-app-template-master\service\venv\lib\site-packages\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 504, in _unpickle
    obj = unpickler.load()
  File "c:\users\dilipan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\pickle.py", line 1210, in load
    dispatch[key[0]](self)
  File "c:\users\dilipan\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\pickle.py", line 1587, in load_reduce
    stack[-1] = func(*args)
  File "sklearn\tree\_tree.pyx", line 607, in sklearn.tree._tree.Tree.__cinit__
ValueError: Buffer dtype mismatch, expected 'SIZE_t' but got 'long long'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import joblib directly instead of importing sklearn.externals, since it is deprecated in latest version of scikitlearn, and joblib can be imported directly -

```
import joblib
```

Comment: @rohith I tried it and it gave me other errors which i have added to the post

Comment: Current error is due to compatibility issue with scikit learn versions(you trained the model on a different version of scikit-learn and current system has a different version). Possible solutions - 1) Retrain on the new system and create a classifier.joblib again. 2) Downgrade your scikit-learn to the version on which the classifier was trained. Also, since your original question is answered, you can accept the answer.